# Get the all the nodes connected to a specific node with relationship

Tags: neo4j

I want to get the all the nodes with relationship(edges) that are connected to this `kim.horne`

I tried to write a query:

```
MATCH p=(c{name:'kim.horne'})-[r:REL]-(d)
RETURN p
```

but this give me the result as shown below:
[image]

You can see I am getting the edge between `eclipse and doughlas`, `susan and nick` etc which I don't want. I am more interested to have edges that are either coming to or going from the node `kim.horne`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Neo4j Browser functionality. Disable "connect result nodes" in neo4j browser and you will only get the relationships from your query.